# Is there a method to drop keyspace without removing schema in cassandra.If there How would i do this?

Tags: cassandra

There is a script which will export Cassandra schema and it will generate two cql files. These files will be called  in restoring schema script.
So previously i have dropped the keyspace. While restoring the schema I am getting an error "cannot add column family to nonexisting keyspaces "graphdb"

Comment: Could you provide the cql files?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are attempting to create the table in a keyspace that has not been created yet. Make sure that the creation happens in the right order in the two cql files that you have exported. First the keyspace needs to be created before you attempt to create the tables.

Comment: The script creates keyspace first then only it will start to create tables.